# Alteração em auditoria em aplicação Java+Spring+Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, spring

Estou com uma tarefa de alterar uma implementação de auditoria em uma aplicação na qual trabalho.

O requisito da auditoria é saber o histórico de alterações, e execuções de determinadas tarefas por determinado usuário. **(Estado Inicial -> Modificação 1 -> ... -> Modificação N)**

O problema, é que a implementação atual salva o estado do objeto serializado Java em um campo *CLOB* na base de dados, e com isso temos alguns problemas:

1. A aplicação já tem mais de 3 anos em produção, e várias alterações foram feitas no decorrer 
   desse tempo, e com isso o Objeto Java foi modificado, mas nenhuma manutenção foi feita na base de dados para o objeto salvo tenha essas alterações. (Por ex: um campo novo adicionado em uma classe).
2. Reverter algo para o "Estado Inicial", ou voltar alguma versão no tempo, cujo o Objeto Java já não reflita o código em execução não é uma tarefa fácil.
3. O simples fato de querer saber o conteúdo do Objeto nessas condições requer que eu recupere no *SVN* a versão da classe qual o objeto foi gerado, e isso pode ser algo difícil, já que não sei exatamente em qual *commit* de código aquele objeto foi salvo.
4. É impossível visualizar o conteúdo do *CLOB* realizando uma simples consulta na base de dados.

Discutindo com outras pessoas, chegamos à algumas possíveis implementações:

- Serializar o objeto Java em JSON (o que facilmente descobriria a versão de código utilizada pelo número de atributos do JSON, e seria humanamente possível ler o conteúdo na base de dados).
- Outra solução que achei, seria utilizar um framework de auditoria que é facilmente integrável com Spring: [Audit4J](http://audit4j.org). Este possui um layout customizável, e também é humanamente legível, e possui diversas [funcionalidades](http://audit4j.org/plugins/) que são muito interessantes. [audit4j](https://github.com/audit4j)

Gostaria de saber nesse caso quais seriam as melhores práticas para realizar uma implementação de auditoria que seja: Humanamente legível (em base de dados), que tenha baixa manutenção, e que os problemas entre versões de códigos não sejam tão dramáticas.

Comment: Acabei de descobrir esse framework (http://javers.org/) irei fazer alguns testes, mas pelo pouco que li ele já tem implementado algumas ideias, e algumas coisas que eu já tinha feito na mão...

Answer (score 1):

Frameworks de auditoria podem ser muito úteis nessa hora, porém existem outras maneiras de criar um esquema de auditoria. Nos lugares onde trabalhei sempre caia em uma das tres opções abaixo:

- Triggers em banco: Criar uma tabela "sombra", igual a tabela origem, e sempre que houver uma alteração nos dados, a trigger salva os dados antigos na sombra. O ponto positivo é que ficaria transparente para aplicação no dia a dia, mas teria que ter cuidado ao dar manutenção na tabela "live".
- Log de eventos: Criar um schema de banco que consiga guardar historicamente os dados. Algo como uma tabela de eventos, que guarda um ID que agrupa todos os dados alterados. Exemplo: a tabela Pessoa tem cinco campos, ao ser alterada, cria um evento de ID 1, com data, que contém 5 elementos de chave valor (nome da coluna, valor da coluna). Esse log de eventos pode ser preenchido via trigger, ou mesmo via aplicação.
- Frameworks de auditoria: ai teria que ver como cada um se comporta, e se ele se encaixa nas suas necessidades.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, eu atualmente estou usando sua segunda sugestão, mas infelizmente a implementação foi feita de uma maneira que dificulta um pouco a manutenção e a rastreabilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou claro se as mudanças nos estados dos objetos devem ser identificadas. Por exemplo, quem alterou determinado atributo em um dado momento?

Minha resposta seguirá supondo que você não precise dessa informação (quem alterou?), bastando saber somente os valores antigos, valores novos e a data de alteração.

Certa vez em um projeto criamos uma arquitetura onde nenhum registro era apagado, e sim sobrescrito.

Todas as tabelas tinham um atributo booleano `hidden` para determinar se determinado registro estava ou não ativo no sistema. E um outro atributo `versao_anterior` que referencia o ID do estado anterior, caso necessário.

Exemplo: uma tabela para manter cadastros de clientes, após inserir os dados de um cliente teríamos:

```
id | nome | telefone | versao_anterior | hidden | data_insercao |
1  | João | 99999999 | null            | false  | 09/02/2015
```

Após a edição dos dados do cliente 1-João, sua tabela ficaria:

```
id | nome | telefone | versao_anterior | hidden | data_insercao |
1  | João | 99999999 | null            | true   | 09/02/2015
2  | José | 12345678 | null            | false  | 12/02/2015
3  | João | 88888888 | 1               | false  | 13/02/2015
```

Perceba que somente o telefone do João mudou do dia 09/02 para o dia 13/02.
Nesse meio tempo, outro registro foi inserido na base sem nenhum problema (id 2).

Dessa forma, para cada instância da entidade cliente é possível rastrear todos seus estados, suas alterações e as datas de cada uma delas.

É só ir listando os registros enquanto `versao_anterior` for diferente de null.

Esse tipo de abordagem é útil quando os dados do sistema não podem ser perdidos.

A desvantagem são:

- não fica armazenado de quem partiu a alteração
- tabelas com vários registros que são alterados a todo momento podem ficar muito grandes em pouco tempo.

Espero ter ajudado.